# Last modify files in folder

Tags: command-line, find, timestamps

In a folder I have files with nanoseconds timestamps.:

```
FileLastestFile.ext
FileOther0.ext
FileOther1.ext
FileOther2.ext
FileOther3.ext
FileOther4.ext
...
FileOther.ext
```

I want to keep only file that are create 10 secondes from the lastest file in that directory (`FileLastestFile.ext`).

I try to use the command `find .. -newermt`, but I don't know which way to specify the `FileLastestFile.ext` timestamp as origin.

Comment: Does the latest file always have name `FileLastestFile.ext`, or you just assumed it?

Comment: We don't know that the last file is FileLastestFile.ext but we want to use it as reference

Answer (score 0):

I think this shows how the time from FileLatestFile.ext could be used, whereby `%x` represents last access, `%y` reprecents last modification and `%z` represents last status change.

```
$ find /folder/ -mindepth 1 -newerct "$(stat --printf=%y /folder/FileLatestFile.ext)" 2>/dev/null
```

Now the trick is to subtract 10 sec. from that.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat

newest=(*.ext(-om[1]))
zstat -F%s.%N -A mtime_of_newest +mtime -- $newest || exit
(( cutoff = mtime_of_newest - 10 ))
older_than_cutoff() {
  local mtime
  zstat -F%s.%N -A mtime +mtime -- ${1-$REPLY} && (( mtime < cutoff ))
}
rm -rf -- *.ext(+older_than_cutoff)
```

(note that for symlinks, it's the mtime of the file after symlink resolution that is considered. If you want the mtime of the symlink itself to be considered instead, remove the `-` in `-om` and add the `-L` option to both `zstat` invocations).